# mousoever and setting background-color

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following html:

```
<img class="img-polaroid img-hover" src="/images/147/09e65aac97caf00c5414593719d0e1b4-medium.jpg?1376027188" background-color="yellow">
```

and css

```
.img-hover:hover{
  background-color: $green-highlight-1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and want to convert to jquery so that we have more control over the color (and animate it). something like:

```
$('.img-hover').on('mouseover', function(){
    console.log("here i am in img-hover");
   $(this).attr('background-color','yellow');
});
```

But this is not working (the console.log works). How do I do set the background-color this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
$(this).css('background-color','yellow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `css` instead of `attr`

```
$('.img-hover').on('mouseover', function(){
    console.log("here i am in img-hover");
   $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.css()` method, like:

```
$('.img-hover').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css('backgroundColor', ' yellow');
});
```